# Javascript regex replace with escaped backslash

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the replace backlash pattern with JavaScript replace method.

```
var display_user = "mycompany\bobandalice";
display_user = display_user.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
document.write(display_user);
```

I am hoping to substitute the backslash in the display_user with two back slashes so the document.write displays "mycompany\bobandalice" on the display.

Instead it displays "mycompanyobandalice".

What am I doing wrong ? (Thanks for your help)

Comment: Your string doesn't have a backslash in it, you have to escape it. `"mycompany\\bobandalice"`

Answer (score 2):

The `display_user` variable does not have the backslash literal at all, so you have nothing to replace.

When `"mycompany\bobandalice"` string is evaluated the `\b` sequence is interpreted as a backspace.

So the `replace` does not replace anything because it's too late - the backslash is not and honestly - was not there ever.

Comment: Thanks @Zerkms - this snippet is from a real life example where the value assigned to display_user does have a single backslash in the value which is returned from an firewall in the meta pattern <domain name><single backslash><user name>.

Comment: @bobwilmes okay. Not sure what it changes though.

Answer (score 0):

The `display_user` string doesn't actually have a backslash character. Try escaping the backslash. Something like this:

```
var display_user = "mycompany\\bobandalice"; 
//                           ^ notice the escaped backslash 
display_user = display_user.replace(/\\/g, '&#92;');
```

Comment: Thank you @Amous - unfortunately the value is actually being passed to the code by a firewall in the meta pattern <domain><single backslash><username>. I'm trying to edit the single backslash to a double backslash to make the meta pattern variable displayable.